# Meaning of this differential equation dy/dt=y

Tags: analysis, derivatives, soft-question

Most of the natural growths/decays follow exponential curve.
That is, their system differential equation is of the form dy/dt=y.
that means rate of growth of a substance at  time 't' is equal to the amount of substance at the same time 't'.
How can I understand this above statement practically?
explain this practically taking an example of radio active decay.
Also,I read that growth of some leaf or something follows logarithmic curve.
How it is different from above growth?
Why it has to be like this?

Comment: I think its more like $\frac{dy}{dt}=ky$ where k is a constant.

Answer (score 3):

The change in a quantity is proportional to the amount you have. This is how interest in a bank works. The amount given to you as interest is proportional to how much money you have already $\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}t} = \alpha y$. The change in money every years equals

$$\Delta y =\left( \frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}t}\right) \Delta t = (\alpha y) \Delta t $$

We call this proportionality *annual percent rate* for this example. In physics it has many names depending on the application.

Comment: In practice, interest compounds a finite number of times per year.

Comment: In the interest of simplicity yes, although technically I did not specify what $\Delta t$ is.

Answer (score 0):

Following a logarithmic curve is the *same* as saying $y=\frac{dy}{dt}$, since that case implies $y=e^t$, where $e$ is the natural logarithm base.